# units of terms in partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, unit-of-measure

Consider: the function f is a function of u, which is a function of a and b.
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial a \partial b} = \frac{\partial}{\partial b}(\frac{df}{du}\frac{\partial u}{\partial a})
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial a \partial b} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{\partial}{\partial b}(\frac{df}{du})+\frac{df}{du}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial a \partial b}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial a \partial b} =  \frac{\partial u}{\partial a}\frac{d^2f}{du^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial b}+\frac{df}{du}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial a \partial b}
$$
The units on the left hand side is [f^2]/([a][b]). I'm struggling to reconcile that with the units of the second term on the right hand side, which is [f][u]/([a][b]).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, the units of $u$ cancel out with the product of the $df/du$ term and the (second) derivative of $u$. You are incorrect in thinking that the units of $\partial^2 f/\partial a\partial b$ are $[f]^2/[a][b]$. The order of the derivative of $f$ does not change the units of $f$. Likewise for $u$.

Comment: To put that another way, since the 'square' is on the partial, not on the function, then the units of $f$ are not squared.   Just write $\tfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial a~\partial b}$ as $\tfrac{\partial ~~}{\partial a}\left(\tfrac{\partial~~}{\partial b}\left(f\right)\right)$.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I understand. I should be ashamed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about position $x(t)$, velocity $v(t)=\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, and acceleration $a(t) = \dfrac{d^2x}{dt^2}$. The units are ft (or m), ft/sec, and ft/sec$^2$. The second derivative is rate of change of the first derivative, so that extra rate of change contributes another /sec in the denominator, but the units of ft do not change.

Thus, in your analysis, both sides have units of $[f]/[a][b]$. On the right-hand side, you have $[f]/[u]^2\cdot [u]/[a]\cdot [u]/[b]$ and $[f]/[u]\cdot [u]/[a][b]$, respectively.